# Using telephony functionality from Android app

Tags: android

I am just getting started developing my first Android app, and one function that I need the app to do is to be able to place a voice call and play a recording into the call.

I have been looking all over the place and I cannot find the ability to do this in the Android SDK. I do see there is com.android.internal.telephony which does seem to offer the ability but I also read that apps are not supposed to use this because it is not part of the SDK.

Am I understanding things correctly that there is no way for an Android app to be able to do this (make an actual voice call)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please mark your accepted answer. This will make others answer you in the future, and will also improve your own score

Comment: Thanks, right, I think I did it now. All I have to do is check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). The specific intent that you're looking for in this case is Intent.ACTION_CALL. For this intent to work you have to put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` into the applications AndroidManifest.xml.

It is not possible to play sounds during conversations. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) topic from the Android Developers web site for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use smth like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+1-800-1234567"));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
```

And do not forget to declare aforementioned permission "android.permission.CALL_PHONE"

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning for something like Internet telephony you have look into this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html